# How come a star ship such as the Enterprise houses children and a school while also being a heavily armed war ship?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would any Federation starship (such as the Enterprise) have any spouses or youth onboard?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5692/why-would-any-federation-starship-such-as-the-enterprise-have-any-spouses-or-y)

It seems quite illogical to house a fully fledged community on a ship that is also frequently sent on dangerous missions. I understand that the crew have family and children, but for them to be a part of the ship instead of a planet or a star base confuses me.

Can anyone shed some light or speculate on this.